# Classicthesis: spacing after paragraph end

Tags: paragraphs, classicthesis

I am using `classicthesis` with the package `ArsClassica` for my master thesis. I saw that in the example document for `ArsClassica` there is some horizontal space before the beginning of a new paragraph, as you can see in picture.
[image: Example of new paragraph]

This does not happen in my document. I tried to look for some settings in the classicthesis.sty file but was not successful. What setting should I look for?

This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,titlepage, fleqn,
           headinclude,footinclude,BCOR5mm,%
           numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty,%
           tablecaptionabove,floatperchapter]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[italian, UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm, empheq}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[style=numeric,hyperref,natbib,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,subfig,beramono,eulermath,pdfspacing,listings,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{environ}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}
\input{arsclassica-settings}


\begin{document}
```

I am new to LaTeX so I based my document on the example document for ArsClassica and left all packages that were loaded since I did not know which ones I could remove without affecting the style or layout. I only then added the ones I needed for my thesis.

p.s.: I did not edit the arsclassica-settings file from the example document (apart from my own title, author name etc.). The file can be found [here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/arsclassica/).

Comment: As usual, a MWE would help us help you, and maybe would have solved your problem already because it would have forced you to break the problem apart in a manageable smaller problem. So, in general the setting is `\parskip` and `\parindent` but to figure out which package/package setting is altering them you really need to see the preamble

Comment: @Bordaigorl I updated my question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm afraid I  have no idea what how this would affect my work. And how this relates to the year 2015. As already mentioned, I found these settings in the example document and used them for my own work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added a link to the file arsclassica-settings

Comment: @mezzanaccio it's a _really_ bad idea to fill the preamble with packages that you don't use. Better to take them all out and just add them back one by one if you need them. Specifically `\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}` tells latex that your file is in the encoding used by previous generations of apple computers. If your editor saves your tex file in any standard encoding such as utf-8 or iso-8859-1 then any non-ascii characters are likely to be garbled in the output. You almost certainly want `inputenc` but with a different encoding option.

Comment: My suspect is that you're ending paragraphs with ``\\``, which is the ***wrong*** way. Leave a blank line (in the TeX input) to denote the end of a paragraph.

Comment: @egreg that thought occurred to me as well...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to bad input by the OP

Comment: @egreg Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 1):

Please always make your examples *complete* documents that reproduce the problem.
If I make an example document from your fragment I get an indent as shown.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,titlepage, fleqn,
           headinclude,footinclude,BCOR5mm,%
           numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty,%
           tablecaptionabove,floatperchapter]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[italian, UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm, empheq}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[style=numeric,hyperref,natbib,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,subfig,beramono,eulermath,pdfspacing,listings,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{environ}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}
\input{arsclassica-settings}


\begin{document}

\section{aaa}

aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 


aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I am trying to achieve paragraph end in the wrong way. I thought the command `\\` would do this, however this is simply a line break. I appear to be missing some of the basics of LaTeX. Inserting an empty line between the two paragraphs achieved what I wanted to achieve.

So none of this had to do with either arsclassica or classicthesis settings.

p.s.: I posted this answer after reading egreg's comment.